# How to get rid of orange or yellow page, after installing 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, freeze, 32-bit

I've an old Dell Inspiron 8600 and it doesn't support `PAE` so I installed `ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386` on it via `forcepae`. (you will probably ask me why are you don't use something like `Lubuntu`,because I need this version for some reason.), after authentication my screen will be orange or yellow or sometimes white, and nothing else.

In `terminal` (`CTRL+ALT+F1`) I also checked `Compiz`, but it's not works either !
any idea ?

Comment: Did you verify your install media? Lubuntu 16.04 LTS is past EOL as flavors of Ubuntu come with only 3 years support, so all 16.04 flavors are EOL except for Kylin & main-Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  I have no idea what you mean by *orange or yellow page*, so a picture may help, or details as to your video card (ie. `sudo lshw -C video` which lists-hardware of class=video).

Comment: Not sure why the `freeze` tag is being using with the question. The system isn't frozen nor is this about **freeze / thaw** which is akin to **suspend / resume**.

Comment: If Dell 8600 doesn't support PAE, why do you use forcepae? When you used forcepae, did you use forcepae, or `forcepae --forcepae`?

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me today and seems to happen about once a month.

In my `~/.bashrc` I've created a function called `xreset` which I can blindly type after opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```bash
xreset () {

    # Reset xrandr to normal, first use: xrandr | grep " connected "
    # HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
    # eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    # DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
    xrandr --output HDMI-0  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0       --rotate normal \
           --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x2160 --rotate normal \
           --output DP-1-1  --mode 3840x2160 --pos 1920x0    --rotate normal

} # xreset
```

This script is also handy the odd time when monitor positions get mixed up in Ubuntu.

For your own version first type `xrandr | grep " connected"` to get your setup:

```bash
$ xrandr | grep " connected"
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
```

For simplicity sake lets assume you only have one 1920x1080 monitor positioned at x=0 and y=0 called `HDMI-0` above. Edit your `~/.bashrc` and insert these lines:

```bash
xreset () {
    xrandr --output HDMI-0  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0       --rotate normal     
}
```

Now the command (technically called a *function*) is available the next time you open a terminal. To make it available in the currently opened terminal type `. ~/.bashrc`. If you are already in the `~` directory (your home) you can simply type `. .bashrc` (note the space after first "`.`").